# Changing linux kernel system call number

Tags: linux-kernel, glibc, system-calls

I wanted to build my own custom kernel with a different syscall table. (same syscalls but in different position/numbers)

I was working on kernel 3.2.29.

Changing the kernel was quite easy:

1) changing the syscall position in ‫‪arch/x86/kernel/syscall_table_32.S‬‬

2) changing the syscall macro number in arch/x86/include/asm/unistd_32.h

3) compiling and installing the new kernel

I switched the syscalls around: `sys_open` took the place and number of `sys_read`, and vice versa.

I figured that if I compile `glibc` with the modified kernel headers, I could have a running system, but unfortunately, it wasn't enough and my system won't boot.

Am I missing something? What else do I need to do in order to have a running system?

---

The steps I have taken are:

1) building and installing the kernel as described in my question

2) extracting the new kernel headers using `make headers_install INSTALL_HDR_PATH=[path]`

3) building glibc with the parameter `--with-headers=[path/include]`

4) I used a live cd to access the file system externally in order to install the new `glibc`, using the `make install install_root=[the original file system]` (so the system won't break during the install)

I hope that the new `glibc` was built properly, but I am not sure.

After that, when booting the system, the boot stops in the (initrafms) shell screen:
I guess I need to rebuild the `initrd`, but how do I compile it according to the new syscall table?

Comment: Please don't close-vote on-topic questions, especially when they have upvotes and answers.

Comment: @JonasWielicki before someone "helpfully" edited it out of the question, it was explained that this was experimentation subsequent to a school assignment to add a new syscall.  While of questionable utility, the change contemplated here certainly calls attention to how things work and that there are many dependencies.  Hacking up a system that no one depends on can be a great way to learn things.

Comment: @ChrisStratton Ah thanks for the clarification. Learning and messing is a good way to go at things, I was just wondring :)

Answer (score 1):

You will have to rebuild *everything*.  Even if all your binaries are dynamically linked, it is possible that the old syscalls were inlined into the binary because many of the C functions are just `return syscall(__NR_somecall,...)`.

You *could* do this manually, but it could be difficult to keep the toolchains straight unless you use a cross compilable toolchain like buildroot, aboriginal or similar.  Pick whichever best suits you (I prefer Rob Landley's aboriginal - http://landley.net/aboriginal/ )

Then to make your initrd just expand the old one using {z,bz,xz}cat oldinit.rd |cpio -id; rm oldinit.rd.  Replace the old kernel modules, libs and binaries with the new and cpio and compress it back (cpio needs the -H newc option) ... or now you can rebuild your kernel and point the initramfs to that directory, but wouldn't recommend that if your initrd may need changed frequently such as if for instance you were testing out a whole new syscall structure and having to debug a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Scrambling the system call numbers is really going to hurt.  You'll at least need to rebuild all of the statically linked binaries on your system and your initrd (if you use one).

Comment: and the startup code in dynamicly build applications might also do one or two syscalls (like exit(2))

Comment: @tmyklebu Do you think `glibc` can be compiled to work on the new system, whitout using the new system to compile it? And if so, then what are the general steps needed to be taken in order to do it?

Comment: @tmyklebu I wanted to have a minimal working system, so i will rebuild only the essential statically linked binaries, but can you give me any lead on who to rebuild the initrd for the new system?

Comment: @tmyklebu are there any more changes that i need to do in the kernel?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said at what point the boot fails, but even if the kernel comes up it is likely that the critical programs contained in the initrd compressed ramdisk would fail because they have the original syscall numbers hard-coded.  You will need to rebuild and repackage those as well.

You might consider first replacing init with a static hello-world type of program to verify that your kernel can support a userspace at all; then look into the details of making all the complexity of a modern linux userspace match.

Comment: i edited the question to describe the process better and when the boot fails

Answer (score 0):

you had to learn to reading the messsage of pansic dump and show us what kenrel panic. Without this information, people can hardly help you or provide you useful suggestion.